# How much of Thor's mythology is accurate?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

Thor has been an integral part of the MCU. If anyone did not know here already, he's actually based on the norse God of the same name 'Thor'.

A lot has been showed about his family,Asgard and his various friends, so my question is - How much of it is Norse mythology accurate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Not very accurate

First, Thor is not merely a Norse god. He appears in several Germanic myths with several slightly different names.

There is not a single story or “canon” for Thor the god of real world myth. This is true of the Ancient Greek and Roman gods as well as many other gods of myth and religion in the world.

That said, if we start to compare the most common and well-documented stories about Thor with the MCU Thor, we quickly find there are vast and fundamental differences.

The most obvious example is that the god of myth is never described as an alien, unlike the MCU character.

Just the summary of the old Norse stories of Thor on Wikipedia show some serious differences:

> Thor bears at least fifteen names, is the husband of the golden-haired goddess Sif, is the lover of the jötunn Járnsaxa, and is generally described as fierce eyed, with red hair and red beard.[1] With Sif, Thor fathered the goddess (and possible valkyrie) Þrúðr; with Járnsaxa, he fathered Magni; with a mother whose name is not recorded, he fathered Móði, and he is the stepfather of the god Ullr. By way of Odin, Thor has numerous brothers, including Baldr. Thor has two servants, Þjálfi and Röskva, rides in a cart or chariot pulled by two goats, Tanngrisnir and Tanngnjóstr (that he eats and resurrects), and is ascribed three dwellings (Bilskirnir, Þrúðheimr, and Þrúðvangr). Thor wields the hammer Mjölnir, wears the belt Megingjörð and the iron gloves Járngreipr, and owns the staff Gríðarvölr. Thor's exploits, including his relentless slaughter of his foes and fierce battles with the monstrous serpent Jörmungandr—and their foretold mutual deaths during the events of Ragnarök—are recorded throughout sources for Norse mythology.

Comment: Whoa, I did not know sif's supposed to be his wife and that he ate those goats after resurrecting them

Comment: Also, the Eddas where we get most of our knowledge of Norse mythology from were written down after Scandinavia became Christianized, so we can't be all that sure if what we do know reflects actual pagan beliefs/stories.

Answer (score 1):

### Accurate(-ish)

There are certainly some key elements that are broadly accurate, at least as related by various drunk Asgardians to a bunch of drunk Norwegians from 1300+ years ago.

We're going to use [*A Beginner’s Guide to Norse Mythology*](https://www.lifeinnorway.net/norse-mythology/) by Jess Scott as our sampler.

> *The Norse universe consists of nine worlds. These worlds are only
> referenced a few times throughout the myths and are not specified, but
> are thought to be (in no particular order) Asgard, Vanaheimr
> (Vanaheim), Jötunheimr (Jotunheim), Niflheim, Muspelheim, Álfheimr
> (Alfheim), Svartálfaheimr (Svartalfheim), Niðavellir (Nidavellir), and
> Miðgarðr (Midgard) – which is our world.*

So that's a big yes. Each of the worlds above seem to exist within the MCU and the Asgard have access to them. They also join to each other through portals at certain times of the year, so it's likely that one would know about the other.

> *These worlds are connected by a great ash tree named Yggdrasil, which runs through the centre of the universe.*

Another yes. We see iconography about Yggdrasil throughout Asgard and it would appear that the nine "realms" listed above share a common connecting thread.

> *The Æsir are the main gods in Norse mythology and live in Asgard.
> Notable Æsir include Odin, Þórr (Thor), Frigg, Heimdall, Týr, Bragi,
> Iðunn (Idunn), Baldr, and Loki (though not always).*

Solid yes here. Many of these characters are people we meet (including Idon, Frigg, Bragi and Loki). Others are mentioned but not met. Sif doesn't appear to be Thor's wife at the point at which he was on Earth, but this may well be a case of '*what happens on Midgard, stays on Midgard*'.

> *Who goes where [after death] is decided by the Valkyries, who collect the souls of
> those “lucky” enough to have died in battle and carry them to their
> destination.*

This is a misinterpretation of what we know happened. The Valkyries fought against Hela to prevent her from leaving the realm of Hel, but given that she's the Goddess of Death, this could easily be misconstrued. It would also appear (courtesy of the end-scene in Thor: Love and Thunder) that Valhalla is an actual factual place where Asgardian warriors go after death.

> *The Dwarfs are responsible for creating some of the Æsir’s most
> valuable possessions, including Mjölnir (Thor’s hammer), Gleipnir (the
> chains that bind the Fenris-wolf), and Sif’s golden hair after Loki
> shaved her bald off as a joke.*

We know from Infinity War that they created Mjölnir for Odin.

> *However, after all this death and destruction, a new world rises up.
> Some Æsir survive Ragnarok*

That's true. We see New Asgard being populated (on Earth) in Endgame.

Comment: So it is about as accurate a depiction of norse mythology as Star Wars is a rendering of biblical events (guy without a biological father is skewered by an officer of the ruling faction at the time, and resurrected by his spiritual father figure later on...). We have two contradicting answers that are both basically correct, within a certain meaning of "correct", which seems to make this pretty much opinion based.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, Star wars hasn't directly named their character on a biblical figure and actually namedropped the bible, while on several instances marvel has specifically stated thor is a norse god